# Start range in v-for="n in 10" from zero

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, v-for

I want to start the range from `0` instead of `1` in `v-for="n in 10"` which results in `1 2 3 .... 10`
Is there a way to do it in Vuejs?

Comment: I'm not sure if this can work to be honest, because `10` isn't an iterable...

Comment: @Sandrooco It will work in Vue.  See dfsq's answer (or the docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-for)

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You can use index (`i`) instead of value (`n`), it will start with `0`:

```
<div v-for="(n, i) in 10">{{ i }}</div>
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
...
```

Comment: While this works, I don't know if I can find this in documentation anywhere! Nice 

Comment: @theHarsh it's said in docs: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html "v-for also supports an optional second argument for the index of the current item."

Answer (score 6):

You can also just subtract a value from your integer

```
<div v-for="n in 10">
  {{ n - 1 }}
</div>
```

This way you can have numbers with a negative value

Answer (score -10):

Just use v-for="i in 10" and you got values 1...10. Also you should use use the key prop like below.

```
<div v-for="i in 10" :key="i">{{ i }}</div>
```

Output

```
1
2
3
...
```